# How can I apply logic for multiple dates in one column/table against multiple dates in another column/table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the job_id from the last job performed before each 'SUSPENDED' step.

Job Table

```
select job_id, stopped 
 from Job j 
 where j.task_id = 100

job_id      stopped
1451200     9/25/2014 14:57
1451201     10/1/2014 21:06
1451202     10/8/2014 13:45
1451203     10/14/2014 14:07
1451204     10/22/2014 14:47
1451205     10/29/2014 21:26
1451206     11/5/2014 14:41
1451207     11/18/2014 17:04
2074993     5/22/2015 15:47
2111136     5/28/2015 15:53
2111137     6/5/2015 14:17
2111138     6/11/2015 14:57
2111139     6/20/2015 14:55
2111140     6/27/2015 15:22
2111141     7/3/2015 15:34
2111142     7/9/2015 14:21
10605814    12/29/2017 22:44
10605815    1/26/2018 19:53
```

WorkFlowHistory Table

```
select wfh_id, dateChange, step 
  from WorkFlowHistory wfh 
  where wfh.step like '%SUSP%' 
    and wfh.task_id = 100

wfh_id   dateChange         step
1628944  11/20/2014 22:04   SUSPENDED
1852694  5/19/2015 14:05    UNSUSPENDED
1861786  5/22/2015 13:24    SUSPENDED
1867582  5/25/2015 14:17    UNSUSPENDED
2006627  7/14/2015 13:24    SUSPENDED
2786512  3/24/2016 17:52    UNSUSPENDED
2811994  4/1/2016 20:02     SUSPENDED
6382968  12/28/2017 17:19   UNSUSPENDED
6537905  2/5/2018 16:57     SUSPENDED
```

The logic I'm considering to do this is a 'case when' statement. My code looks something like this.

```
select
 case when stopped >= DT_CHG - interval 7 day 
      and stopped < DT_CHG 
      then job_id 
 end as susp_job_id
from Job j
join (select dateChange DT_CHG, task_id
       from WorkFlowHistory
       where step = 'SUSPENDED')wfh on wfh.task_id = j.task_id
where wfh.task_id = 100
```

My ideal result set would look like this

```
id      stopped     wfh_id  dateChange  step
1451207 11/18/2014  1628944 11/20/2014  SUSPENDED
2074993 5/22/2015   1861786 5/22/2015   SUSPENDED
2111142 7/9/2015    2006627 7/14/2015   SUSPENDED
```

as these are the three job_id's that meet the criteria of being within a week prior of the suspended step dateChange.

However, when I run this it appears to only be calculating the stopped dates against the oldest dateChange, so only this returned as a result.

```
id      stopped     wfh_id  dateChange  step
1451207 11/18/2014  1628944 11/20/2014  SUSPENDED
```

How can I get this logic to work properly so that it will calculate against each dateChange as opposed to the most recent one? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should produce the results you want, but I'm not positive since you didn't include the schema or an example of all of the relevant data in your example data. It should be faster because it uses join instead of a sub-query.

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.stopped,
    a.wfh_id,
    a.dateChange,
    a.step
FROM WorkFlowHistory a
JOIN Job b
ON a.task_id = b.task_id
    AND b.stopped BETWEEN a.dateChange - interval 7 day AND a.dateChange - interval 1 day
WHERE a.step = 'SUSPENDED'
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I'm still new so I'm not sure exactly all the information to add in my questions.